# Store data after mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

This is my problem. I have a table in my database in which there are two columns, ID and ANSWER. In this database there are more rows with same ID, so I want to save all the results with this id in an array.
the sql code is:

```
$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM Answer WHERE userId = :userId and qId = 'q6'";
$stmt6 = $conn->prepare($sql6);
$stmt6->execute(array(':userId' => $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']));
```

now to fatch the results I don't know if I have to use

```
$result6 = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

or

```
$result6 = $stmt6->fetchAll();
```

EX.
`ID  ANSWER
    q6  abba
    q6  bbaa`

i would save in an array like this for example:

```
$array=("abba","bbaa");
```

then i would pass this array to a script in javascript.

Comment: `array_column` since php5.5 or `foreach` will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barmar, your solution partially works. i've written this:

```
$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM Answer WHERE userId = :userId and qId = 'q6'";
    $stmt6 = $conn->prepare($sql6);
    $stmt6->execute(array(':userId' => $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']));
    $count6 = $stmt6->rowCount(array(':userId' => $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']));

    $answer6 = array();

    while ($result6 = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $answer6[] = $result6->answer;
    }
```

then i want to pass this array to a script, so:

```
<script>
  var num = var ans6 = '<?php echo $count6; ?>';
  var ans6 = '<?php echo json_encode($answer6); ?>';

  for(var i=0; i<num;i++){
     alert(ans6);
  }
```

the result is a popup in which is written "["abba","bbaa"]".

but if i write

```
for(var i=0; i<num;i++){
     alert(ans6[i]);
  }
```

the popup shows first"[" and then " " "

Answer (score 1):

You can either call `$stmt->fetch` in a loop, pushing each row onto the resulting array, or you can call `fetchAll` once -- it returns an array of all the rows. So the following are equivalent:

```
$array = array();
while ($row = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

and:

```
$array = $stmt6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

If you want an array with just the value of a single column, rather than objects representing the whole row, the loop will be easier:

```
while ($row = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $array[] = $row->q6;
}
```